# Default micronaut application not running

Tags: java, maven, gradle, command-line-interface, micronaut

Not being able to execute the **default micronaut application** using basic cli commands. This problem has occured on both the Maven and Gradle default projects. I don't understand why I'm having issues running the app.

The repective default project base directories contain the mvnw and gradlew files so I don't think it's a problem with maven/gradle being out of date on my computer or anything along those lines.

I've checked the class path being passed into the arguments in both the gradlew and mvnw bat and cmd files. Their respective wrapper.jar paths are being passed in as classpath arguments.

Here's some images.

[Maven error message, similar error occurs when trying to run with gradle:](https://gyazo.com/28528c63b0e74a76613ebf30bf17826a)

[Base directory of maven project:](https://gyazo.com/cb81bd913cd8f42fd57ca404ebed10a6)

[Gradle error message:](https://gyazo.com/9e7daff55b93347738aca4719e74a9e1)

[Base directory of gradle project:](https://gyazo.com/99b6c0aaed2a1ad661a9f4a97306cf07)

[Parent directory image:](https://gyazo.com/ac742fd7ff1f04b2f8d273875bd37e30)

UPDATE: I just tried downloading someone else's project directory from a [guide on micronauts website](https://guides.micronaut.io/creating-your-first-micronaut-app/guide/#solution) I unzipped it and used the ./gradlew run command, the server seems to be [up and running](https://gyazo.com/52a5d5994a143632a26af224845f1606). The zip comes with initial and completed subdirectories each with their own micronaut application inside, they run too using the same gradle command.

This leads me to believe that there was something wrong with my micronaut installation.  Maybe it's shipping a faulty default application (that's not configured properly)?

Comment: "This leads me to believe that there was something wrong with my micronaut installation." - I don't see anything in your question that suggests that to be the case.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new micronaut application in my C drive with a different directory, it worked. I think it has something to do with the original path variable having too many spaces and -  in it. Making the classpath (in the gradlew.bat) unreachable essentially.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you don't have the wrapper support files in your project.

```
~ $ mn create-app somedemoapp
| Generating Java project...
| Application created at /Users/jeffbrown/somedemoapp
~ $ cd somedemoapp/
somedemoapp $ rm -rf gradle
somedemoapp $ ./gradlew run
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
```

(notice that I deleted the `gradle/` folder before attempting to run the project)

Some people don't check in the `gradle/` directory to source code control because they don't understand its purpose.

Comment: As I stated in my original post, I checked the classpath argument being used inside the script, they both linked a gradle/maven wrapper jar. And the jar does exist in the specified directory. An image of the .bat file using the wrapper jar in class path https://gyazo.com/e16bb1832126787c0e0221faf177c509. An image of the gradle> wrapper sub directory https://gyazo.com/484c10faa838159b966f2a6360a3393c. And I've also checked the Jar to see if the specified .class exists, it does. It's the same case with the maven version.

Comment: also here's an image inside the jar https://gyazo.com/e5eb01758b059e2b7f996bfd0682c07a. I don't understand why it isn't being found as it's clearly in the classpath and the class exists in the jar . I'm going to try and replace the classpath variable with the physical directory of the gradlewrapper jar, hopefully that works.

Edit; I changed the classpath argument to the path of the jar without using any variables. Still gives me the same error.

Comment: If you can share a sample project which demonstrates the problem, it would be trivial to troubleshoot.